# Обновление версии зависимостей gradle

Tags: gradle, зависимости

Пытаюсь обновить версию зависимости Apache commons compress путем добавления в файл build.gradle. По итогу получается такой список зависимостей:

```
dependencies {
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation")
implementation("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
implementation("org.projectlombok:lombok")
implementation("com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305")
api("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")
api("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
api("org.postgresql:postgresql")
implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc")
implementation ("org.yaml", "snakeyaml", "2.0")
implementation ("org.apache.commons", "commons-compress",  "1.24.0")
```

}

В итоге, после подгрузки gradle зависимостей в дереве зависимостей остается зависимость со старой версией.
Зависимость со старой версий тянется из api("org.testcontainers:postgresql")
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как можно сформировать build.gradle, чтобы версия обновилась во всем дереве?